# session_set_save_handler set $_SESSION data manually?

Tags: php, session

I am writing a custom session handler I can not find this in the documentation, but am I suppose to set the $_SESSION data manually after reading from a source with `read`?

```
private function setSaveHandler()
{
    $value = session_set_save_handler($this->handler);
    register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

    if (!$value) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Could not set the session\'s save handler');
    }
}
```

My actual handler's read method:

```
public function read($sessionId)
{
    // Retrieve data from a custom source. Save in $data variable.

    // Assign: $_SESSION = $data
}
```

Do I need to manually populate the session or should this somehow be done automatically by PHP?

Comment: do you want to store the values on `$data` in `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: @MiteshPant yes, but the question is whether PHP would do this automatically or not. Because even though you have a session wrapper you are still talking to it with session methods. So I would expect the data to end up back in the $_SESSION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. PHP takes the return value from the read() handler, unserializes it and populates $_SESSION with the result automatically.

Comment: I would have expected as much, but something is going wrong here. I don't see anything happening. Thanks for confirming my suspicion though.

Comment: Try to localise the problem. Return a hardcoded value from the read() to confirm handler is properly registered. If it works, than problem lies somewhere in the storage logic.

Comment: I was struggling a long time with this since it just fails silently. But I was testing it with a string that was not a proper session_encoded string. It instantly works now with a proper string. It would be nice to have some kind of error message here but then again I will not retrieve a bad string anymore. Thanks for the help.